# Good recommendations on diet plan

Tags: diet, bodybuilding, nutrition

My Weight is 77 kg and height is around 5 ' 9 inch.

I am doing body building and i want to share my diet plan with you so that i can get some best recommendations from you:

I go to gym in the morning around 8 am wihtout eating or drinking anything and after 1 hour of workout i come home but while coming home on the way i drink coconut water and after coming home i drink 1 glass of juice and after 10 - 5 minutes of shower i take my breakfast which includes 2 eggs with 1 chapati and little 100 gms of chickpeas.

After that i go to office and in office i eat 1-2 oranges,1-2 apples and in lunch i eat 3-4 chapatis.

In dinner i eat maggies noddles some day and some day i eat 1- 2 chapatis(mostly i skip this) and before sleeping i drink 500 ml of milk daily.

On saturday and sunday i eat chicken.

Note:My trainer says without supplements you wont be able to build your body.

So if there is any suggestion or something then please give me...

Comment: You need protein. Around 40% of your food intake should be protein., preferably lean sources: Chicken, Eggs, Milk. Cut down on your bread (chapatti), you should try to replace some of those with sources of protein. Your trainer is right, with that diet you will not be able to build a significant amount of muscle at any reasonable pace.

Comment: @JJosaur Thanks for showing your interest but he is telling me to take protein supplements which i dont want to as 1 of my friend told me that because of intake of protein supplements he is experiencing lots of hair fall with increase in sex drive that is why i have decided not to take supplements and good supplements are way too costly for me.

Comment: @JJosaur Can you recomment me good diet plan like how much and what i should eat in breakfast lunch and dinner and through out the day?

Comment: You don't pay me, so no. There are some good resources here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/wiki/getting_started#wiki_step_4.3A_fixing_your_diet

Answer (score 4):

You need to be specific about your goals first and eat accordingly. Muscle building always comes with a price. The price is in terms of hard work, diet and proper rest.

Let's break it down.

You said, "I go to gym in the morning around 8 am without eating or drinking anything".

That's a mistake. No matter what you want, a pre-workout meal is a must, especially in the morning hours. Something that body can absorb easily, like a home made shake(I'm not saying protein) there are plenty of shakes you can make at home. Else, some milk and egg whites can do. If you train with no food in your system, your body draws energy and nutrients from muscles and as a result you'd not see the result you want to. Contrary to old belief that fat loss happens during workout, no, it doesn't immediately, but hours after it. So, eat at least an hour before you workout. Also, in the morning you are already in starvation mode and your body needs energy after those hours of sleep. Jumping directly to workout, you'd do a disservice to yourself.

Second is post workout meal. You need to eat enough protein and carbs after workout to fill in the requirements and pump nutrition to your muscle cells.

Your lunch and dinner should contain good amount of macros and micros with at least a gram of protein per pound of body weight, as a daily intake from what you eat. Along with that, you need to eat enough fruits and vegetables to get the micro nutrients. Your primary source of nutrition is food.

Regrading your instructor's advice, you can prove him wrong if you eat well, workout properly and rest well. Supplements are to compensate the deficit in food, they are not food.
For a good diet plan, check in forums and YouTube. The best diet plan is the one you choose for yourself keeping complete nutrition in mind.

Comment: It really seems like you are professional trainer because your answers are really awesome.do you want to comment something on my lunch and dinner please??

Comment: @Learning: Thanks for the kind words, but no, I'm not a pro, but I have learned quite a bit from years of practice, listening to different pros, some from my own experience, and some from here and other forum. We have quite a few great people here who have helped everyone in great way. For Lunch and dinner I should say, eat balanced diet. Like vegetables, some lean meat like chicken, some clean carb, like brown rice, or whole bread(but don't over eat carbs). All you need to take care is, you get enough from food. So, increase the protein intake, and keep calorie consumption as per your goals.

Comment: Don't eat processed food like maggie and stuff. Replace them with good carbs like oats, or brown rice or whole bread. Something that tastes good, is not always good for body. Your fruit intake is fine, but fruits mostly provide you with calories and micros, and not the protein you want for your goals. As I said earlier, 1 gram/body weight is required, so you are 77 kgs, that is 170 lbs. So your protein consumption should be around 150-170 grams through out the day. Including your lunch dinner and breakfast. Also, rest well, because muscles only grow when you rest well, eat well and workout.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your guidances.i really really appreciate your suggestions and guidances.do you use any social media through which i can be in touch with you if it is ok with you please because i think i can learn alot from you.

Comment: You are welcome and I'm always glad to help. Unfortunately no, I just hangout on forums like this, not on any other social media. If you have any queries, you can comment on any of my threads and we can start a discussion from there, and move it to live chat. This site has that feature.

Comment: Ok so can we talk in chat room so that we can have a good discussion there :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49475/discussion-between-learning-and-xcodezone).